# Performing implementation in pandas using datetime intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have an example data of every minute as below:

```
datetime                       value
2021-04-10 00:01:00+00:00.      0
2021-04-10 00:02:00+00:00.      0
2021-04-10 00:03:00+00:00.      0
2021-04-10 00:04:00+00:00.      1
2021-04-10 00:05:00+00:00.      0
2021-04-10 00:06:00+00:00.      1
2021-04-10 00:07:00+00:00.      0
2021-04-10 00:08:00+00:00.      1
2021-04-10 00:09:00+00:00.      1
```

I would like to create another column(expected) with a logic which samples the data every 3 minutes and :
a) assign 0 to the new column when at least three of the sampled values are 0
b) and assigns 1 when you have less than three sampled values with 0

The expected output should be like this:

```
datetime                       value.   expected
2021-04-10 00:03:00+00:00.     [0,0,0]    0    
2021-04-10 00:06:00+00:00.     [1,0, 1].  1
2021-04-10 00:09:00+00:00.     [0,1,1].   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert values to datetimes and then use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by 3 minutes with convert values to lists and last value of datetime, then check if at least one `1` by `any` with convert column to integers:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'].replace('\.','', regex=True))

df = (df.resample('3Min', on='datetime', closed='right')
        .agg({'value':list, 'datetime':'last'})
        .reset_index(drop=True))
df = df[['datetime','value']]
df['expected'] = df['value'].apply(any).astype(int)
print (df)
                   datetime      value  expected
0 2021-04-10 00:03:00+00:00  [0, 0, 0]         0
1 2021-04-10 00:06:00+00:00  [1, 0, 1]         1
2 2021-04-10 00:09:00+00:00  [0, 1, 1]         1
```